# Task management with google contacts?

Tags: tasks

HI

I want an google widget for homepage or something else where I can create,manage and assign tasks to my google or invited contacts.

```
Please suggest me anything.which will be great help
```

Thanks&Regards

kumar kasimala.

Comment: superuser is for computer hardware and software related questions **only**. Phones, websites, and electronic devices are considered **off topic** as defined by the site scope laid out in the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

Google calendar allows you to create tasks on you calendar and assign participants... google contacts is integrated wit google calender so you could just select your contacts as participants fairly easy.